# How to make a linear layout add a child view in a new line?

Tags: android, layout

I want to define a layout that it's orientation is horizontal, but if width of the child views exceeds the width, it adds the new child view in a new line.

can it be done?

Comment: Have You try with WRAP_CONTENT

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For this you will need a FlowLayout whose custom implementation is given on this link

**Courtesy : Nishant Nair**

http://nishantvnair.wordpress.com/2010/09/28/flowlayout-in-android/

Comment: and how do I use it? just flowLayout.addView and it adds it they way I specified? and what is the xml file for?

Comment: Whilst working with Nishant's `FlowLayout` I noticed some things which were superfluous so I tweaked it a bit. See [here](http://adilatwork.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/android-horizontal-flow-layout.html). This version also takes into consideration margins on child views.

Answer (score 1):

You can use RelativeLayout as the parent view, and put many LinearLayouts in it, giving each of them a separate id, and adjusting their position relative to each other (in your case "below").

Comment: But it would not adjust if the views inside the row exceeds the row width

Comment: @FtheBuilder What if you set the width of the LinearLayout to fill_parent?

Answer (score 0):

NOp, :) not in the way you want it(not with linear layout). I am not sure but I think in java there was a FlowLayout that starts from left and keep moving to right when there is no space left it starts new row. But in android there is no such a layout.

But you can do some workarounds for this problem. There is a lot of differen solution but it cannot be done with linear layout. If you set orientation tho horizontal in will never go to new line.

as @Rasel suggested the best solution for you is to use gridview and do nothing about the orientation

Comment: if I extend LinearLayout and Override the addView function, is there a way to calculate the width of the child views ?

Comment: yes there is on measure function, but I suggest to do not bother with this, just use a gridview

Comment: do not reinvent a wheel :), gridview is you solution not linear layout

Comment: I'll try both GridView and FlowLayout and post back.

Comment: I think there is no flow layout for android , but I am not sure

Answer (score 0):

You can use grid view as layout to achieve this